# Extracting child node from JSON Response using SoapUI-Groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am new in soapUI and still exploring the groovy script,I need your help. 
this is my json response:

```
 {
  "userId": 36,
  "userTypeId": 2,
  "name": "Name_7",
  "surname": "R",
  "friendlyName": "",
  "employeeId": "1000245",
  "role": "engineer",
  "dateOfBirth": "1985-07-09T01:46:23.213",
  "fPicture": "",
  "deleted": false,
  "visitingUserId": null,
  "mineId": 1,
  "crewId": null,
  "versionAutoId": 10002814,
  "externalId": null,
  "email": null,
  "externalLoginId": null,
  "sourceJson": null,
  "description": null,
  "propertyJson": null,
  "userGroups":       [
     {"groupCode": "ALL_USERS"},
     {"groupCode": "MTCC_ADMIN"}
  ],
  "userAccessDto":       {
     "userAccessId": 36,
     "userId": 36,
     "password": "XKjgXD6o/pjHaHd6swvkB8TiQ6L1kEC8307sV94F2GeiFnb4QXUZJhk8rdQJgvdJujSPK/NoM94CMtp8X51ExTEwMDAyNDU=",
     "deleted": false
  }
   },

{
  "userId": 37,
  "userTypeId": 5,
  "name": "Name_9",
  "surname": "R",
  "friendlyName": "",
  "employeeId": "1201",
  "role": "engineer",
  "dateOfBirth": "1985-07-09T01:46:23.213",
  "fPicture": "",
  "deleted": false,
  "visitingUserId": null,
  "mineId": 6,
  "crewId": null,
  "versionAutoId": 10031438,
  "externalId": null,
  "email": null,
  "externalLoginId": null,
  "sourceJson": null,
  "description": null,
  "propertyJson": null,
  "userGroups":       [
     {"groupCode": "ALL_USERS"},
     {"groupCode": "MTCC_ADMIN"}
  ],
  "userAccessDto":       {
     "userAccessId": 37,
     "userId": 37,
     "password": "a05qHK+KrXXmHTFFGQN9JRQWkHnjJX+SCmqBK1PAa2f95I8e20JNt5GaVxL5nGbnTReobSZ/vej3qCAsZK9Q7DEyMDE=",
     "deleted": false
  }
```

}
]

How can I get the Password value for userId = 36 and pass it to my other test cases? I searched a lot but couldn't find a proper guide on existing asked questions. I should mention that my response changes from time to time, so I can't assume it as string.
Appreciate all your responses.

Comment: Update your question with valid json file and add what you have tried..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use `JsonSlurper`.

For a Json file like this: **Example.json**

```
{
  "userAccessDto": {
    "userAccessId": 37,
    "userId": 37,
    "password": "a05qHK+KrXXmHTFFGQN9JRQWkHnjJX+SCmqBK1PAa2f95I8e20JNt5GaVxL5nGbnTReobSZ/vej3qCAsZK9Q7DEyMDE=",
    "deleted": "false"
  }
}
```

Groovy Code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def root =new JsonSlurper().parse(new File ('/tmp/example.json'))

println root.userAccessDto.password
```

Comment: thanks for your reply yes I tried it with JsonSlurper and it worked. I'll attach the response. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Ronak Glad ! Enjoy coding..!

Answer (score 1):

```
import net.sf.json.groovy.*

def i, newUserId, hashPass, empId;
//get test case from other project or from the same one
project = 
testRunner.getTestCase().getTestSuite().getProject().
getWorkspace().getProjectByName("API_Services_v3.0.321")
testSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName("Users");
testCase = testSuite.getTestCaseByName("Users-Retrieve a list of users");
```

// run test case

```
runner = testCase.run(new 
com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap(), false);
Thread.sleep(3000)
```

//get JSONresponse from the testStep and parse it

```
def responseContent = testCase.getTestStepByName("ApiV1UsersGet -Get 
all").getPropertyValue("response")
slurperResponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)
```

//get userId from the TestSuite property to compare against

```
newUserId = 
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("Users").
getPropertyValue("idOfUser")
```

//loop throught the JSONresponse

```
for(i=0;i<slurperResponse.resource.size();i++)
{
            if(slurperResponse[i].userId == newUserId.toInteger() )
            {
                            log.info("Hash Pass is" +slurperResponse[i].userAccessDto.password);
                            log.info("Employee Id is" +slurperResponse[i].employeeId);
                            hashPass = slurperResponse[i].userAccessDto.password
                            empId = slurperResponse[i].employeeId

                            break;
            }
}
```

//assign hashPassword and empId to the testSuite properties for next test step

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("Users")
.setPropertyValue("Hash_Pass",hashPass.toString())
 testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("Users").
setPropertyValue("EmployeeId2",empId.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you found a way, though I'd call it the hard way. You could've simply use JSONPath option in Property Transfer.
A query like this works:

> $.[?(@.userId==36)].password

Further, you could turn the userId to a parameter for dynamic checks.

[image: Property Transfer with JSONPath]

Comment: oh Wow! I will give this a try for sure, yeah what I need is a dynamic value for userId. as I said it will change in each test run. is there any way I get the userId value from my TestSuite property? I have userId property which its value is transferred from POST API. how can I point $.[?(@.userId==36)].password that get the value lets say " 36" from my property ?

Comment: @Ronak, I tried to do it, but it seems not possible There is still an easy way to use JSONPath in Groovy instead of slurper: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/How-can-I-use-a-variable-in-Property-transfer/td-p/142204